# Escaping special characters in sqlite when using = in query in android

Tags: android, sqlite, special-characters

I have database with a column itemitem that looks like this

aaabbb

aaa%bbb

aaa_bbb

aaa'bbb

My query looks like this where itemitems is one of the above fields;

```
    itemitems = itemitems.replaceAll("'","''");
    itemitems = itemitems.replaceAll("%","\\\\%");  // use \\\\ to generate \%
    itemitems = itemitems.replaceAll("_","\\\\_");

    itemitems = "'" + itemitems + "'";
    String query = "select * from " + table_ITEMS + " where itemitem = " + itemitems + " ESCAPE '\\'";
```

I get the following exception:

```
SQLiteException: near "ESCAPE": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: select * from items where itemitem = 'aaa\_bbb' ESCAPE '\'
```

However if I use itemitem like instead of itemitem =, I don't get the exception. But, I don't get the  exact match either. This works fine for finding aaa'bbb with the itemitem = query.

It seems that the `=` query doesn't accept the ESCAPE clause. How can I escape the `%` and `_` special characters?

Answer (score 0):

The `=` operator does not have an ESCAPE clause because it does not interpret the pattern characters `%` or `_`. Only LIKE would use those.

Comment: Thanks CL. After testing many different patterns I came to this conclusion as well. I use "like" to search the read only database using an escape clause, then I use "=" when I change the retrieved data to write it to a user database to make sure the user database didn't have the same name for the data.